# How do you count the sum of arithmetic progression using while loop?

Tags: matlab, math

I'm new to MATLAB and coding, so any help is much appreciated. I wanted to make a program that calculates the sum of an arithmetic progressions of natural numbers where you input N as the total natural number of terms in the sequence and the common difference between the terms is 1 and calculating it using the while loop. I have no idea how to code this program so I will be much grateful if anyone could help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

total number stands for N in your question. diff stands for difference of each term in arithmetic progression. start stands for initial value of given arithmetic progression.

```
total_number=5;
diff=3;
start=1;

sum=0;
i=1;
while i<=total_number
    tmp=start+diff*(i-1);
    sum=sum+tmp;
    i=i+1;
end
```

I hope this answer helps.